# Bounding sum of multinomial coefficients by highest entropy one

Tags: st.statistics, pr.probability, it.information-theory, co.combinatorics

When does the following hold?

$$\sum_{(i_1,\ldots,i_k)\in E}
\frac{n!}{i_1! \ldots i_k!}
\le  \exp(n H^*)$$

where $H^*=\max_{(i_1,\ldots,i_k)\in E} -(\frac{i_1}{n}\log \frac{i_1}{n}+\ldots +\frac{i_k}{n}\log \frac{i_k}{n})$ and E is some subset of {$ \{( i_1,\ldots,i_k):i_1+\ldots+i_k=n \}$}

Motivation: this is a generalization of Chernoff's bound to n tosses of fair k-sided dice where E represents the hypothesis we make about that sample. Another motivation is reconciling tight special-case [Chernoff bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#Theorem_for_additive_form_.28absolute_error.29) with looser but more general bound given by [Sanov's theorem](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/sanovs.png)

Examples: when k=2, it can be proven to hold for sets of coefficients where first component of the coefficient is less than n/2 (ie [here](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/binomial.png)).

When k=3, it seems (empirically) to hold for sets of coefficients where sum of first two components is ≤n/2. For instance, for n=10, highest entropy term gives upper bound of (2/3)^3 *10^5 whereas exact sum is 12585. Since k=3 multinomial coefficients lie in a 2-simplex, the 21 multinomial coefficients in this set can be visualized below. Top vertex represents coefficient (0,0,10)

[image] [<sup>(source)</sup>](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/multinomials.png)

For higher k, we can look at similar sets, ie corners of the (k-1) simplex. I tried few values and it seems to hold for coefficients where sum of first k-1 components is below n/(k-1)

Here's how you'd check it in Mathematica

```
getit[n_, k_, c_] := (
   all = Select[Tuples[Range[0, n], k], Total[#] == n &];
   e = Select[all, Total[Most[#]] <= c &];
   hterm[x_] := If[0 < x < 1, x Log[x], 0];
   H[event_] := -Total[hterm /@ (event/n)];
   exact = Total[Multinomial @@@ e];
   upper = Exp[n Max[H /@ e]];
   exact < upper
);
(* Check bound for k=3, n=10, with i1+i2<=5 *)
getit[10, 3, 5]
```

**Update 8/18**
Leandro gives a bound on a single multinomial coefficient which gives [Sanov's theorem](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/sanovs.png) if we consider that there's at most $(n+1)^k$ multinomial coefficients in any set E. It seems that to generalize the [proof](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/binomial.png) of the tighter binomial bound to, say, trinomial coefficients, one would need to prove the following inequality first

$$p_1 \log q_1 + p_2 \log q_2 + p_3 \log q_3 \ge q_1 \log q_1 + q_2 \log q_2 + q_3 \log q_3$$

Where p and q add up to 1. For each q, the set of p's for which the above bound holds also gives us the hypothesis for which we can give tight Chernoff-like bound. Empirically, this bound seems to hold for p's "bounded away" from the uniform distribution. Black circle below represents q, blue region is the set of distributions p where the bound above holds. My Mathematica [notebook](http://yaroslavvb.com/research/qr/mo-multinomials/mo-multinomials.nb)

[image] [<sup>(source)</sup>](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/cross-entropy-bound.png)

**Update 8/24**: the bound holds for sets of coefficients of the form $i_1 a_1 + \ldots + i_n a_n \le C$ where $a_1\ldots a_n$ are arbitrary non-negative numbers, details in answer

Comment: I've no answer to your question. but a minor note on your *Mathematica* code: you can use this definition for hterm instead hterm[x_] := If[0 <= x <= 1, x Log[x], 0]; , and change the formula for exact to Total[Multinomial @@@ e] .

Comment: Good point, @@@ notation is way more legible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take arbitrary non-negative reals $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ consider and consider set $E$ of n-tuples $(i_1,\ldots,i_n)$ satisfying the following

$i_1 a_1 + \ldots + i_n a_n \le n(a_1 \exp - a_1 + \ldots +a_n \exp -a_n), \sum_k i_k=n, i_k\ge 0$

Sum of multinomial coefficients in this set is bounded by the highest entropy one.

Proof, define $q_i=-\log a_i$ and observe that ${q_1}^{i_1} \cdots {q_n}^{i_n}\ge \exp(-n H(q))$. Then proceed in the same manner as the the analogous [proof](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/binomial.png) for binomial coefficients, substituting this inequality in the last step of derivation.

Note that if any $a_i$ is 0, the bound is vacuous. Here are some examples of sets of trinomial coefficients defined in this way for random $a_i$'s. Black dot is the highest entropy coefficient.

[image] [<sup>(source)</sup>](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/multinomial-sets.gif)

One way of to think of these sets is the following -- view multinomial coefficients as multinomial probability distributions. Then I pick my "highest entropy" distribution q and consider the set of distributions $p$ for which $p_1 \log q_1 + \ldots p_n \log q_n \ge q_1 \log q_1 + \ldots + q_n \log q_n$. That includes q, and all distributions "further away" from the uniform distribution than q

Answer (score 2):

Hi Yaroslav, With the additional hypothesis you are considering, I guess that the inequality can be proved following the text that you linked.

Fix any probability vector $(p_1,\ldots,p_k)$ and consider $E\subset \{1,\ldots, n\}^k$ such that 
$$
E\subset\left\{(i_1,\ldots,i_k); \sum_{j}^ki_j=n\ \text{and }\ p_j\geq\frac{i_j}{n} \right\}
$$

For any element of $E$, we have

$$
\sum_{j}^k p_j\log p_j\leq \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{i_j}{n}\log p_j.
$$
Therefore
$$
-n\left(\sum_{j=1}^k-p_j\log p_j \right)\leq \sum_{j=1}^k i_j\log p_j.
$$
Exponentiating both sides we get
$$
\exp\left(-n\left(\sum_{j=1}^k-p_j\log p_j \right)\right)\leq p_1^{i_1}\ldots p_k^{i_k}.
$$
For the other hand, we have that
$$
1=(p_1+\ldots+p_k)^n=\sum_{i_1,\ldots,i_k}\frac{n!}{i_1!\ldots i_k!}p_1^{i_1}\ldots p_k^{i_k}\geq \sum_{(i_1,\ldots,i_k)\in E}\frac{n!}{i_1!\ldots i_k!}\exp\left(-n\left(\sum_{j=1}^k-p_j\log p_j \right)\right),
$$
where the first summation is taken over all sequences of nonnegative integer indices $i_1$ through $i_k$ such the sum of all $i_j$ is $n$.

So we get that
$$
\sum_{(i_1,\ldots,i_k)\in E}\frac{n!}{i_1!\ldots i_k!}\leq\exp\left(n\left(\sum_{j=1}^k-p_j\log p_j \right)\right)\leq e^{n H^*}.
$$

Comment: Is it essential to disallow 0's in the coefficients? Allowing 0's would allow to relate to existing bounds, like the one I linked

Comment: Also, it seems your set E contains at most 1 element

Comment: The difference between you proof and the one I linked is that they base their proof on an entropy inequality that holds for a range of coefficients. In your case, your starting inequality holds for just one coefficient, so it can be replaced by equality. It gives a bound on a multinomial coefficient in terms of it's entropy. There's at most (n+1)^k coefficients in any set E (+1 comes if we allow 0's), so we can bound the sum over these coefficients over the set by (n+1)^k Exp[n H^*] .... that's the same as Sanov's theorem

Comment: You right. I did not reply before, because I am investigating the generalization of the case two inequality. I have one, but it also seem stupid as my previous argument. If I have time I will think about it little bit more.

Comment: I added "proof by picture" that the binomial proof can be generalized...what's missing is an explicit characterization of the set of p's where H(p,q)>H(q)